# Has there ever been a Family Guy episode that featured the screen porch?

Tags: identify-this-episode, family-guy

[image]

Has there ever been a Family Guy episode that featured the screen porch?

I don't think I have ever seen an episode where the screen porch was featured.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has featured occasionally:

[image]

Some examples are:

1. **[Halloween on Spooner's Street](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_on_Spooner_Street)** (S09E04) - [here is a video of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QeZrsveWU2U&feature=youtu.be).
   [image]
2. **[Ready Willing and Disabled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ready,_Willing,_and_Disabled)** (S03E15)
   [image]
3. **[Wasted Talent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasted_Talent)** (S02E20) - when Peter and Brian try and find the "golden ticket" to get entry to the Pawtucket Brewery they get drunk in the sun room. That's the episode the image above is from.
4. **[Stewie Loves Lois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewie_Loves_Lois)** (S05E01) - I'm not 100% on this one, but I'm fairly certain in this episode, to get the attention of Lois, Stewie starts drawing on the walls in the sunroom.

If you're interested, a few other forums have had this question asked. Feel free to peruse some of their answers at [Tickld](http://m.tickld.com/pic/t/142563) and on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/familyguy/comments/1m2ple/dae_notice_that_the_griffins_never_use_the/).

Comment: I added two more pictures and replaced the first one with a better quality one. (All pictures are screenshots taken myself from the episodes). However, I could not find the scene you are talking about in the fourth example, so it's possible you are remembering it wrong.

Comment: I find it really interesting how the graphic style has developed, just compare example 2 (Season 3) with example 1 (Season 9): The wall actually is transparent now.

Comment: Since @Nate's "answer" seems more an addition to this answer, you might consider incorporating it as it will no doubt disappear (or at least be overlooked).

Answer (score 1):

Also S2 E10 - Brian and Stewie have a conversation in there.  Brian is in the green chair and the room is surrounded by screens.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment on an answer than an answer unto itself.

Answer (score 1):

Season 2, episode 2. "Holy c***" meg walks in from school into the sun room to a conversation with peters non biological father Francis Griffin.